# Facing strange error while instantiating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am going to open a new fragment in OnCreate method.

But while instantiating a fragment i am facing an error " Method call expacted " as shown in image

[image]

And my AnnouncementFragment class declaration is as below ..[image]

I had search for this problem but didn't find solutions.

Comment: You forgot to write the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AnnounceFragment fragment = new AnnounceFragment();
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed the `new` keyword before `AnnouncementFragment`. To instantiate a java object you have to use the [new](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) operator, which takes care of allocating memory for the object and returns a reference to it. Change from

```
AnnouncementFragment fragment = AnnouncementFragment();
```

to

```
AnnouncementFragment fragment = new AnnouncementFragment();
```